# How to perform various operations on a pandas DataFrame column containing a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, in which one column `resources` consists of a list of tuples. For example, take the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                   "resources": [[(1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 9)], 
                               [(3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 4)], 
                               [(9, 0), (2, 6), (5,5)]]
                  })
```

Now, I want to add the following columns to my DataFrame, which contain the following:

- A column `first` containing a list with the unique first elements of the tuples in `resources` (so basically a set of all the first elements)
- A column `second` containing a list with the unique second elements of the tuples in `resources` (so basically a set of all the second elements)
- A column `same` containing the number of tuples in `resources` having the same first and second element
- A column `different` containing the number of tuples in `resources` having different first and second elements

the desired output columns would look like this:

- `first`: `[[1, 2], [3], [9, 2, 5]]`
- `second`: `[[1, 3, 9], [1, 4], [0, 6, 5]]`
- `same`: `[1, 0, 1]`
- `different`: `[2, 3, 2]`

How to achieve this in the least time consuming way? I was first thinking of using `Series.str`, but could not find enough functionality there to achieve my goal

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer I tried using Series.str, which did not work. Then I went looking for all functionality there and could not find anything more useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df["first"] = df["resources"].apply(lambda x: [*set(i for i, _ in x)])
df["second"] = df["resources"].apply(lambda x: [*set(i for _, i in x)])
df["same"] = df["resources"].apply(lambda x: sum(len(set(t)) == 1 for t in x))
df["different"] = df["resources"].apply(
    lambda x: sum(len(set(t)) > 1 for t in x)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id                 resources      first     second  same  different
0   1  [(1, 3), (1, 1), (2, 9)]     [1, 2]  [1, 3, 9]     1          2
1   2  [(3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 4)]        [3]     [1, 4]     0          3
2   3  [(9, 0), (2, 6), (5, 5)]  [9, 2, 5]  [0, 5, 6]     1          2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the purpose of the "*" before set?

Comment: [What does the star and doublestar operator mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/15497888)